# Custom method using apply with multiple condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apply

```
lst = [np.nan,["google_newyork","google_NewYork","google_LA"],["google_newyork","google_LA"],["google_newyork","google_newyork"]]
  
df = pd.DataFrame(lst, columns =['subcompanies_matches'])
```

I am trying to change the value of one column based on some condition which are detailed on the function below using the apply method, however i am not able to get the expected output below

```
df = ([True, True, False, True])
```

```
def check_subcompanies(subcompanies_concat):
    """ Returns True if subcompanies match else False """
    if  subcompanies_concat != None: 
        subcompany1 = subcompanies_concat[0].lower()
        subcompany2 = [x.lower() for x in subcompanies_concat[1:]]
        if subcompany1 in subcompany2:
            return True
        else:
            return False
    else subcompanies_concat == None:
        return True
df = df.apply(check_subcompanies)
```

however i got this error, "The truth value of a Series is ambiguous". so i am wondering if apply, is the appropriate function, for this kind of issue ?

Comment: the definition of dataframe is not true, and it returns error, please show your df in more clear method, and what you want from the check_subcompanies

Comment: sorry, now i made the appropriate correction

Comment: please try the answer, your defined dataframe doesn't have any advantage to the ```lst```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,(you don't need pandas dataframe):

```
lst = [["google_newyork","google_newyork"], None, ["google_newyork","google_NewYork","google_LA"], ["google_newyork","google_LA"]]

def check_subcompanies(subcompanies_concat):
    """ Returns True if subcompanies match else False """
    if  subcompanies_concat: 
        subcompany1 = subcompanies_concat[0].lower()
        subcompany2 = [x.lower() for x in subcompanies_concat[1:]]
        if subcompany1 in subcompany2:
            return True
        else:
            return False
    elif(subcompanies_concat == None):
        return True


list(map(check_subcompanies, lst))
```

output:

```
[True, True, True, False]
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, however it appears that the result sometimes changes, [True, True, True, False]